How can I check that an F# script file is valid without executing it?
I have some F# script files that I would like to maintain. Ideally, it would be caught by CI if someone attempts to merge an invalid script.
How can I check that they are valid but without executing them?
Invalid.fsx
this is not valid code

# Not a real command, should return a non-zero exit code
dotnet fsi --check ./Invalid.fsx


You might wind up with more useful answers if you convey some extra context about the intended overall use case - directives in a source file (especially #r, but probably more) influence whether parsing succeeds or not, but presumably another other likely concern will be the side effects of actually running stuff etc. As it stands, things are a bit http://xyproblem.info

@RubenBartelink I added a note - it's about preventing invalid scripts getting past CI

Could you try to compile it to check? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33468298/

You might be able to use F# compiler services if you really want to get your hands dirty

As far as I'm aware, there is no dotnet fsi command to only check for code errors.
If you are sure that you will be interacting with .fsx files then you could look at compiling these using the fsc.exe compiler - which will spit out any errors it encounters in the compilation process.
To use it, this command should suffice:
fsc.exe --target:exe test.fsx

with test.fsx being the file you wish to check for errors.
This will compile the given file but not run it - generating an exe file at the end if no errors were encountered.
Note that fsc.exe is not normally in Windows' PATH, so you'll have to find it. For Visual Studio 2022 it's normally found here:
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\FSharp\Tools\fsc.exe

If you are testing an F# project (i.e. it contains a .fsproj file and .fs file) it's quite a bit easier as you can use dotnet build in the directory of your F# project. This will build the project without running it and report any errors.
To learn more about using fsc.exe it has a pretty complete help file which is accessible with:
fsc.exe --help

you can do the same with dotnet build too:
dotnet build --help

